# How to compare MySQL time() in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

just a quick question.

Lets say I've got a few rows of data with time saved in db as time() datatype and the values are: 01:00:00, 03:00:00, 07:00:00

Now having these 3 I need to get largest time and produce an html select with the last option as (largest value + 1). Having done that and having another html select below with options saying > longer than and < shorter than, I need to write a SQL query to look for lets say longer than : 04:00:00

How could I achieve this?

@Edit 1

Okay so here is my code, it's codeigniter based so I'll just give you an idea

That's array of my html select options:

```
array('' => 'None', '<' => 'Longer than', '>' => 'Shorter than')
```

That's what I use to compare input with db

```
if($durationOperator == '>') {
        $this->db->where('flightTime >', $duration);
    } elseif($durationOperator == '<') {
        $this->db->where('flightTime <', $duration);
    }
```

And that's how I generate my dropdowns:

```
public function getLongestFlightTime() {

        $this->load->helper('Time_helper');

        $schedules = $this->getAllActiveFlights();

        $longestTime = 0;

        foreach($schedules as $schedule) {

            $flightTime = convertHoursMinutesSecondsToSeconds($schedule['flightTime']);

            echo $flightTime.' > '.$longestTime. '<br/>';

            if($flightTime > $longestTime) {
                $longestTime = $flightTime;
            }
        }

        echo $longestTime;

        return $longestTime;
    }

    public function generateDurationDropDown()
    {
        $longestDuration = gmdate("H", $this->getLongestFlightTime()) + 2;
        $i = 1;

        $dropDown[0] = 'None';

            while($longestDuration > $i) {
                array_push($dropDown, $i);
                $i++;
            }

        return $dropDown;
    }
```

The generation of dropdown seems to be okay tho there is probably smoother way to do this?

The results are completly wrong tho, I think it is to do with my where clause as $duration from input would be 1 or 2 or 3 etc (the value of option in html select)

Comment: Can you please give more detail into what you're trying to do. Code you have attempted or desired output.

Comment: To get time comparison you could use something simple like 'SELECT fieldname WHERE timeField > xx:xx:xx'

Comment: Edited to give you more info, could that be the fact that my WHERE clause looks like WHERE flightTime > 1 and not flightTime > 1:00:00 ?

Comment: Yes, that would be a problem. It should be `WHERE flightTime > '1:00:00'`. The time needs to be in quotes.

Comment: If i'm not really bothered as this value is going to be only displayed a lot and not really much math based functions are going to use it, could I just use float for purpose of storing the time?

Comment: Got it, just changed $duration; to $duration . ':00:00'; Thank you!